# EditText Is Not Visible With Open Keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a fullscreen activity with a fullscreen ImageView in the background. I have an EditText placed in the middle of the screen using `gravity:center`. When the keyboard opens I want the EditText to move up as shown in the picture below so that the whole EditText is always visible. I have attempted using  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` however the problem with this is that my Image in the background is also resized which is not desirable. Furthermore, since the gravity is set to center this results in there being a gap between the EditText and keyboard so that it is still in the center. I have tried using a scrollView however I did not know how to obtain the position at which the keyboard ends so that I can move my EditText to that position. I have also tried `adjustPan` however this had no effect since the EditText is `200dp` in height and the gravity is set to center so the user always starts typing in the middle of the EditText which is still visible.

XML

```xml
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/picturedisplay"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/pic_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#9945D199"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:hint="Enter text here..."
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:maxLength="250"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:id="@+id/pic_textbox"
            android:layout_weight="90"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:text="200"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:id="@+id/char_rem_view"
            android:layout_gravity="end"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imgClose"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:text="Flip Cam"
    android:padding="20dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/snap"
    android:text="Capture"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Flash"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/imgOpen"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addText"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:text="Add Text"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:padding="20dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/addPic"
    android:text="Add Pic"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
    android:id="@+id/save_photo"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:padding="20dp"/>
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your xml code?

Comment: @Jayanth i posted xml

Comment: If possible put EditText into its own ViewGroup such as LinearLayout/RelativeLayout or FrameLayout. It should ensure that the edit box is always visible when has focus.

Answer (score 1):

add this in your `EditText` xml,

`android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"`

I'm not sure this method is not fit your needs, I hope you can help:)

Answer (score -1):

Open up your menifest.xml find your activity and add this single line

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

or

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

your activity tag should look like below

```
<activity
    android:name="com.my.MainActivity" //Change this to your.package.ActivityName
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

or

```
<activity
    android:name="com.my.MainActivity"  //Change this to your.package.ActivityName
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
</activity>
```

**Update 1**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picturedisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pic_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#9945D199"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pic_textbox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:hint="Enter text here..."
        android:maxLength="250"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/char_rem_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="200"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/imgClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Flip Cam" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/snap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Capture" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/imgOpen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Flash"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Add Text"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addPic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Add Pic"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save_photo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Save"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I mentioned in the question that none of these work because adjustResize resizes the image in the ImageView and this is undesirable and adjustPan doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Oh I am sorry I hav'nt noticed. Well is it necessary for you to set the gravity=center of your EditText?

Comment: Could you please advise me how to alter my code so that I can set the position of the EditText without hardcoding the position in dp or pixels, I want it to be relative to the screen size. Normally I would use layout_weight however with a frameLayout that doesn't work. This is why I used gravity=center

Comment: try with gravity = bottom to your EditText.

Comment: Can you show me the actual layout you want? any sketch image your layout have many views hidden

Comment: Have you tried using ScrollView? I was too facing a similar issue with Fragments, I use the  ScrollView in the parent FragmentActivity and add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" to the FrameLayout that hosts fragments. The android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" smooths the transition between the fragments and can be dropped.